# Truncate and insert string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've table which contains column with values:

```
id  string

1   aaabbbfff

2   aaabbbfffff

3   aaabbbffff

4   aaabbbfffffff

5   aaaaabbbffffff

6   aaaaabbbffffff

7   jjjjjbbbffffff

8   gggggtttffffff
```

And I've unchangeable part (kkk) which I need to insert at the beginning of the string. In result - 'kkkbbbfff'

I use UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
  SET string = 'kkk' +
  SUBSTRING(string, 3, LEN(string))
from
  [dbo].[mytable]
```

It works for 1, 2, 3, 4 rows. But exp. in 5 and 6 rows contains more symbols 'a' and code `SUBSTRING(string, 6, LEN(string))` not work. How I can change all rows in one statement?

In result I need table:

id  string

```
1   kkkfff

2   kkkfffff

3   kkkffff

4   kkkfffffff

5   kkkffffff

6   kkkffffff

7   kkkffffff

8   kkkffffff
```

Comment: Could `a` appear anywhere else in the string?

Comment: I need insert 'kkk' part before first symbol 'f' in each rows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no. But other rows can contain different symbols like in rows 7 and 8

Comment: You need to be **way** more specific here. You say insert but clearly you are replacing parts of the string. Don't make us guess what you really want to accomplish. Do you really want to replace all the `a`'s at the start with the same number of `k`'s or is this just a dumbed down version of your data and it is actually a lot more complex?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I need insert 'kkk' part before first symbol 'f' in each rows. But before string part 'fff..' can miscellaneous number of characters and difference symbols

Comment: So you need to locate where in the string the first `f` is then concatenate `<string before f> + <kkk> + <string from f>` ?

Comment: That would give you this string for item 5: `aaaaabbbkkkffffff` - is this what you want?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 
I need to trim the string before the first symbol 'f' and then insert the 'kkk'

Comment: What about the `bbb` part where you have a specific example that should end up as `kkkbbbfff` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 'bbb' will be delete. All symbols before 'f' part will be delete. You can look in result table

Answer (score 1):

The following update will replace from the beginning the substring up until the first `f` with `kkk`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET string = 'kkk' + SUBSTRING(string,
                               CHARINDEX('f', string),
                               LEN(string) - CHARINDEX('f', string) + 1)
```

If you instead need to insert `kkk` in before the first `f` and retain the beginning substring you can use `STUFF()`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET string = STUFF(string, CHARINDEX('f', string)-1, CHARINDEX('f', string)-1, 'kkk')
```

Comment: This code UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET string = 'kkk' + SUBSTRING(string, CHARINDEX('f', string)) not work

Comment: The substring function requires 3 argument(s).

Answer (score 0):

in your example you could do it like:
removing the all 'a' with `REPLACE` and adding the kkk

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
  SET string = 'kkk' + REPLACE(string, 'a','')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
  SET string = 'kkk' + RIGHT(string, len(string)-3)
from
  [dbo].[mytable]
```

Comment: If you always need to replace the first three charaters of the string, this will work.

Comment: but he wrote: "But exp. in 5 and 6 rows contains more symbols 'a'"

Comment: Didn't even notice; but also it is not super easy to understand what he means - clearly he needs to specify exactly what he is after.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET string = replace (string, left(string, charindex('f', string)-1), 'kkk')
FROM [dbo].[mytable]
```